# A map that is $(n-1)$-positive but not $n$-positive

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $\phi : M_n(\mathbb{C})\to M_m(\mathbb{C})$ be a linear map.  $\phi$ is called *$k$-positive* if the map $\phi^{(k)} : M_{kn}(\mathbb{C}) \to M_{km}(\mathbb{C})$, defined by evaluating $\phi$ entrywise, takes positive matrices to positive matrices.

It is a well-known [theorem of Choi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choi%27s_theorem_on_completely_positive_maps) that if $\phi$ is $n$-positive, then $\phi$ is actually $k$-positive for all $k$.  Is this result optimal?  I.e., is there, for each $n$, a map $\phi : M_n(\mathbb{C})\to M_m(\mathbb{C})$ which is $(n-1)$-positive but not $n$-positive?  ($m$ can be whatever you want; dependent on $n$, say.)